# Self join a table and calculate return with of values

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

So I am having troubles with calculating the return of a portfolio.
For example, I have the following table with the following values:

```
create table StockReturn (
    Id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Datedate null,
    Value decimal(10,2) null
);
insert into stockreturn values (1,'2000-1-1', 43534.12);
insert into stockreturn values (2,'2000-1-2', 41534.12);
insert into stockreturn values (5,'2000-1-2', 32341.12);
insert into stockreturn values (3,'2000-1-3', 46534.12);
insert into stockreturn values (4,'2000-1-4', 44234.12);
```

What I would like to calculate is the Return of the porfolio value on the 2000-1-2 with respect to 2000-1-1 in percentage. Please be aware that we also have multiple values with the same date.

I have the following code but this gives me the wrong value for 2000-1-3

```
select a.id, a.date, sum(a.value) as totalValueA, sum(b.value) as 
totalValueB
from stockreturn a
left join stockreturn b on a.datum = b.datum+1
group by date;

Result: 
1   2000-01-01  43534.12    Null
2   2000-01-02  73875.24    87068.24
3   2000-01-03  93068.24    73875.24
4   2000-01-04  44234.12    46534.12
```

What i would like to see is a fourth column with the name "Percentage Return" which calculates the value of (value @ 2000-01-02 - Value @ 2000-01-01) / Value @ 2000-01-01 and assigns this to the date 2000-01-02.

Comment: The first rows totalValueB should not be Null, Are you sure the given data is currect?

Comment: Please explain your logic.

Comment: I want to calculate the return for the specific date. So on 01-01 my porfolio was 43534.12 and in 01-02 it was 73875.24. I want the next column (with the Null as first value) to calculate the difference between those.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect: Stop trying to code your overall goal. Find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) Don't just dump wrong code. Give the least cut & paste & runnable code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why. [mre]

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()`:

```
select a.date, sum(a.value) as totalValue,
       lead(sum(a.value)) over (order by a.date) as next_totalValue
from stockreturn a
group by date;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i am looking for the return on 2000-1-2 with respect to 2000-1-1. Your answer would let me calculate the return but not for the correct date. What I would like to do is (value @ 1-2) - (value @ 1-1) / (value @ 1-1) and assign this outcome to 2000-1-2